# How to calculate floating point numbers?

Tags: floating-point

> Here are two locations in memory:
>
> ```
>  0110 | 1111 1110 1101 0011
>  0111 | 0000 0110 1101 1001
> ```
>
> Interpret locations 6 (`0110`) and 7 (`0111`) as an IEEE floating point number. 
>   Location 6 contains bits [15:0] and location 7 contains bits [16:31].

```
Floating Point -
   Locations 6 and 7: 0000 0110 1101 1001 1111 1110 1101 0011
   The number represented is 1.101 1001 1111 1110 1101 0011 × 2^(-114)
```

Is my answer correct?
I am unsure exactly what the [16:31] and [15:0] relate to/mean?

Comment: Not really a math question. You may have better luck on a computing site.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can't we migrate this for him? It's been done for at least one my questions and maybe one of yours.

Comment: @Robert, I suppose we could vote to close and migrate, or flag for moderator attention and suggest migration, but I don't know enough about computing sites to suggest one as the target.

Comment: @Gerry, I was looking at programmers.stackexchange, but a question there about converting from single precision float to half precision was closed for being "off-topic" (which of course does not always mean it really is off-topic. The scope is said to include questions about "algorithm and data structure concepts."

Comment: @Robert, if you find an appropriate site, go ahead and take whatever steps you can to migrate. I'm happy to let OP do the work of finding a better site and the work of contacting the moderators to migrate, or let OP delete here and post elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The `[16:31]` and `[15:0]` refer to locations in the binary representation of a $32$-bit integer. You have interpreted this correctly.

When in doubt about technical problems, always consult <s>Wikipedia</s> an expert.

[image]

In your case the number is
`0` || `00001101` || `101 1001 1111 1110 1101 0011`

The sign is positive.

The biased exponent is `1101` $ = 13$, so the actual exponent is $13 - 127 = -114$, assuming single precision.

So the answer you have is correct:
$$2^{-114} \times (1.101 1001 1111 1110 1101 0011)_2$$

Comment: If this question didn't advocate trusting Wikipedia at any level on any topic, and if I was the issuer of the bounty, I think I would award it to this answer.

Comment: I'd let the typo slide, though ("techincal").

Comment: Hows that? Better?

Comment: Endianness do matter. You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22320772/3275970)

Comment: Agreed, endianness matters. I am assuming that the bits in memory correspond to a 32 bit word (in the order stated) and that the exponent and mantissa have the MSB on the left.